# Authorize core keeps looping MVC 4 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I have implemented a custom attribute which basically checks if the user is within a certain group. If yes it handles the unauthorized request. The issue I am having is that it the code keeps looping and finding to pinpoint the issue. If i had

My code is below:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
        {
            var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN");

            UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

            if (userPrincipal != null)
            {
                PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = userPrincipal.GetGroups();

                bool found = groups.Any(item => item.Name == "NAME OF GROUP HERE");

                if (found)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                {"action", "AccessDenied"},
                {"controller", "Error"}
            });

    }
```

I have added the above in the global.asax and added to the filters.

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
 {
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeADAtttribute());           
 }
```

Hope someone can assist me.

Thanks

Comment: Does the Error Controller or AccessDenied action have the filter applied? If so, that'd would cause it to loop. It looks like that's the case as your applying the filter at the global level rather then at the controller level. Add a check to the filter to the effect of "This is error controller OR User check passed" maybe.

Comment: The Error controller and accessdenied does not have the filter applied. Which part of the filter should i be applying the check to?

Comment: Your adding the filter to the `GlobalFilterCollection` ... That makes it global to all controllers and actions. Why would you think that this would not include `ErrorController` as well? In your place I would remove the global filter, and add the attribute to each controller in your application that requires this authorization check.

Comment: Ok i wanted to stop a particular group actually accessing the application hence thats why it was added into the global.asax. One thing i noticed is if i add base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filtercontext) within the HandleUnauthorizedRequest method it does not loop but it does not redirect the filter.result which is odd

Comment: With this in place you can never serve them the access denied page - it also requires the user to pass the check!

Comment: Cheers i understand now because when i enter the page it is obviously hitting the error controller which has the filter applied. So basically need a static error page.

Comment: I suggested in my first comment to simply add a new logical check to the authorization to allow it to pass if it's the error page, or the user check passed....